# xrandr shows disconnected DisplayPort with Intel Graphics

Tags: graphics, xrandr, intel-graphics, displayport

I have 4 physical ports on my motherboard, VGA, HDMI, DVI, and DisplayPort.  Normally I use HDMI and DVI, but I'd like to switch to HDMI and DP.  However, the output of xrandr shows DP as always disconnected:

```
$ xrandr --verbose
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Identifier: 0x43
    Timestamp:  284401515
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Clones:     HDMI3
    CRTCs:      0 1 2
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
  1920x1080 (0x4a) 148.500MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  67.50KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  60.00Hz
HDMI1 connected primary 1920x1080+1920+0 (0x4a) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 509mm x 286mm
    Identifier: 0x44
    Timestamp:  284401515
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Gamma:      1.0:1.0:1.0
    Brightness: 1.0
    Clones:    
    CRTC:       0
    CRTCs:      0 1 2
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    EDID: 
        00ffffffffffff000469d223e3a40000
        2417010380331d782ad945a2554da027
        125054b7ef00d1c0814081809500b300
        714f81c08100023a801871382d40582c
        4500fd1e1100001e000000ff0044394c
        4d54463034323231310a000000fd0032
        4b185311000a202020202020000000fc
        00415355532056533233390a20200140
        020322714f0102031112130414050e0f
        1d1e1f10230917078301000065030c00
        10008c0ad08a20e02d10103e9600fd1e
        11000018011d007251d01e206e285500
        fd1e1100001e011d00bc52d01e20b828
        5540fd1e1100001e8c0ad09020403120
        0c405500fd1e11000018000000000000
        000000000000000000000000000000e9
    aspect ratio: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, 4:3, 16:9
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
  1920x1080 (0x4a) 148.500MHz +HSync +VSync *current +preferred
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  67.50KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  60.00Hz
  1920x1080 (0xe6) 148.500MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2448 end 2492 total 2640 skew    0 clock  56.25KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  50.00Hz
  1920x1080 (0xe7) 148.352MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  67.43KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  59.94Hz
  1920x1080i (0xe8) 74.250MHz +HSync +VSync Interlace
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  33.75KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1094 total 1125           clock  60.00Hz
  1920x1080i (0xe9) 74.250MHz +HSync +VSync Interlace
        h: width  1920 start 2448 end 2492 total 2640 skew    0 clock  28.12KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1094 total 1125           clock  50.00Hz
  1920x1080i (0xea) 74.176MHz +HSync +VSync Interlace
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  33.72KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1094 total 1125           clock  59.94Hz
  1680x1050 (0xeb) 119.000MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1680 start 1728 end 1760 total 1840 skew    0 clock  64.67KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1059 total 1080           clock  59.88Hz
  1280x1024 (0xec) 135.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1296 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock  79.98KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock  75.02Hz
  1280x1024 (0xed) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock  63.98KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock  60.02Hz
  1440x900 (0xee) 88.750MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1440 start 1488 end 1520 total 1600 skew    0 clock  55.47KHz
        v: height  900 start  903 end  909 total  926           clock  59.90Hz
  1280x960 (0xef) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1376 end 1488 total 1800 skew    0 clock  60.00KHz
        v: height  960 start  961 end  964 total 1000           clock  60.00Hz
  1280x800 (0xf0) 71.000MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1360 total 1440 skew    0 clock  49.31KHz
        v: height  800 start  803 end  809 total  823           clock  59.91Hz
  1152x864 (0xf1) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1152 start 1216 end 1344 total 1600 skew    0 clock  67.50KHz
        v: height  864 start  865 end  868 total  900           clock  75.00Hz
  1280x720 (0xf2) 74.250MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1390 end 1430 total 1650 skew    0 clock  45.00KHz
        v: height  720 start  725 end  730 total  750           clock  60.00Hz
  1280x720 (0xf3) 74.250MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1720 end 1760 total 1980 skew    0 clock  37.50KHz
        v: height  720 start  725 end  730 total  750           clock  50.00Hz
  1280x720 (0xf4) 74.176MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1390 end 1430 total 1650 skew    0 clock  44.96KHz
        v: height  720 start  725 end  730 total  750           clock  59.94Hz
  1440x576 (0xf5) 54.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1440 start 1464 end 1592 total 1728 skew    0 clock  31.25KHz
        v: height  576 start  581 end  586 total  625           clock  50.00Hz
  1024x768 (0xf6) 78.800MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1040 end 1136 total 1312 skew    0 clock  60.06KHz
        v: height  768 start  769 end  772 total  800           clock  75.08Hz
  1024x768 (0xf7) 75.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1328 skew    0 clock  56.48KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  70.07Hz
  1024x768 (0xf8) 65.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock  48.36KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  60.00Hz
  1440x480 (0xf9) 54.054MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1440 start 1472 end 1596 total 1716 skew    0 clock  31.50KHz
        v: height  480 start  489 end  495 total  525           clock  60.00Hz
  1440x480 (0xfa) 54.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1440 start 1472 end 1596 total 1716 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  480 start  489 end  495 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
  832x624 (0xfb) 57.284MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   832 start  864 end  928 total 1152 skew    0 clock  49.73KHz
        v: height  624 start  625 end  628 total  667           clock  74.55Hz
  800x600 (0xfc) 50.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  856 end  976 total 1040 skew    0 clock  48.08KHz
        v: height  600 start  637 end  643 total  666           clock  72.19Hz
  800x600 (0xfd) 49.500MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  816 end  896 total 1056 skew    0 clock  46.88KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  604 total  625           clock  75.00Hz
  800x600 (0xfe) 40.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock  37.88KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock  60.32Hz
  800x600 (0xff) 36.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  824 end  896 total 1024 skew    0 clock  35.16KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  603 total  625           clock  56.25Hz
  720x576 (0x100) 27.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   720 start  732 end  796 total  864 skew    0 clock  31.25KHz
        v: height  576 start  581 end  586 total  625           clock  50.00Hz
  720x480 (0x101) 27.027MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   720 start  736 end  798 total  858 skew    0 clock  31.50KHz
        v: height  480 start  489 end  495 total  525           clock  60.00Hz
  720x480 (0x102) 27.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   720 start  736 end  798 total  858 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  480 start  489 end  495 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
  640x480 (0x103) 31.500MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  720 total  840 skew    0 clock  37.50KHz
        v: height  480 start  481 end  484 total  500           clock  75.00Hz
  640x480 (0x104) 30.240MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  704 end  768 total  864 skew    0 clock  35.00KHz
        v: height  480 start  483 end  486 total  525           clock  66.67Hz
  640x480 (0x105) 25.200MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.50KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  60.00Hz
  640x480 (0x106) 25.175MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
  720x400 (0x107) 28.320MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   720 start  738 end  846 total  900 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  400 start  412 end  414 total  449           clock  70.08Hz
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Identifier: 0x45
    Timestamp:  284401515
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Clones:    
    CRTCs:      0 1 2
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    aspect ratio: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, 4:3, 16:9
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
HDMI3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Identifier: 0x46
    Timestamp:  284401515
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Clones:     DP1
    CRTCs:      0 1 2
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    aspect ratio: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, 4:3, 16:9
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
  1920x1080 (0x4a) 148.500MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  67.50KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  60.00Hz
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Identifier: 0x47
    Timestamp:  284401515
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Clones:    
    CRTCs:      0 1 2
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Identifier: 0x48
    Timestamp:  284401515
    Subpixel:   no subpixels
    Clones:    
    CRTCs:      3
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter:
```

The closest I've gotten has been manually adding the mode then attempting to switch to it:

```
$ xrandr --addmode DP1 1920x1080
$ xrandr --auto --output HDMI1 --mode 1920x1080 --primary --output DP1 --mode 1920x1080 --left-of HDMI1 --output VGA1 --off
xrandr: Configure crtc 1 failed
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  21 (RRSetCrtcConfig)
  Serial number of failed request:  47
  Current serial number in output stream:  47
```

Right now with my second monitor plugged into the DVI port the output of xrandr is:

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1080     60.00  
HDMI1 connected primary 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 509mm x 286mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1440x576      50.00  
   1024x768      75.08    70.07    60.00  
   1440x480      60.00    59.94  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
HDMI2 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 509mm x 286mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1440x576      50.00  
   1024x768      75.08    70.07    60.00  
   1440x480      60.00    59.94  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
HDMI3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1080     60.00  
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Driver info:

```
$ sudo lshw -c video 
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:29 memory:f0000000-f03fffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:f000(size=64)

$ modinfo i915
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-91-generic/kernel/drivers/gpu/drm/i915/i915.ko
license:        GPL and additional rights
description:    Intel Graphics
author:         Intel Corporation
author:         Tungsten Graphics, Inc.
firmware:       i915/bxt_dmc_ver1.bin
firmware:       i915/skl_dmc_ver1.bin
firmware:       i915/skl_guc_ver4.bin
srcversion:     F88AC02BE47BB41FC2F1D77
...
```

I'm not sure what the next step for debugging this would be.  I've never used the DisplayPort before, so it may well be an issue with the Intel Drivers.

EDIT:
To clarify my ports.  HDMI1 is my actual HDMI port, HDMI2 is my DVI port, HDMI3 appears to be a clone of DP1, which is my DisplayPort.  HDMI1 and HDMI2 work fine, but both DP1 and HDMI3 always show disconnected.

Comment: It's possible that what is externally a DP is internally a HDMI port, as far as the graphics card is concerned, and the internal `DP1` port is not connected to anything physical at all.  If I understood what you did correctly, whenever you plug in a monitor in the physical DP, it shows up under `HDMI1`. If that's correct, then `HDMI1` is the name you must to access the physical DP. If it's not correct, please explain the problem in more detail.

Comment: @dirkt HDMI1 is the actual HDMI port, DP1 and HDMI3 appear to be clones of each other, and are my actual DisplayPort.  See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
# inxi -SGay# inxi -SGIay
System:
  Host: ab85m Kernel: 5.8.14-1-default x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 10.2.1
  parameters: mitigations=auto consoleblank=0 video=1440x900@60
  Desktop: Trinity R14.0.8 tk: Qt 3.5.0 info: kicker wm: Twin 3.0 dm: TDM
  Distro: openSUSE Tumbleweed 20201014
Machine:
  Type: Desktop System: ASUS product: All Series v: N/A serial: N/A
  Mobo: ASUSTeK model: B85M-E v: Rev X.0x serial: MB-1234567890
  UEFI: American Megatrends v: 3602 date: 04/04/2018
Graphics:
  Device-1: **Intel Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core** Processor Integrated Graphics
  vendor: ASUSTeK **driver: i915** v: kernel bus ID: 00:02.0 **chip ID: 8086:0402**
  Display: **x11 server: X.Org 1.20.9 driver: modesetting** unloaded: fbdev,vesa
  alternate: intel display ID: :0 screens: 1
  Screen-1: 0 s-res: 2560x2520 s-dpi: 120 s-size: 541x533mm (21.3x21.0")
  s-diag: 759mm (29.9")
  **Monitor-1: DP-1** res: 2560x1440 hz: 60 dpi: 109 size: 598x336mm (23.5x13.2")
  diag: 686mm (27")
  **Monitor-2: HDMI-3** res: 2560x1080 hz: 60 dpi: 97 size: 673x284mm (26.5x11.2")
  diag: 730mm (28.8")
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel HD Graphics (HSW GT1) v: 4.5 Mesa 20.1.8
  compat-v: 3.0 direct render: Yes
Info:...running in: konsole inxi: 3.1.08
# xrandr --listproviders
Providers: number : 1
Provider 0: id: 0x47; cap: 0xf (Source Output, Sink Output, Source Offload, Sink Offload); crtcs: 3; outputs: 5; associated providers: 0; name: modesetting
    output VGA-1
    output DP-1
    output HDMI-1
    output HDMI-2
    output HDMI-3
# xrandr | egrep 'onnect|creen|\*' | grep -v disconn | sort -r
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 2560 x 2520, maximum 16384 x 16384
HDMI-3 connected 2560x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 673mm x 284mm
DP-1 connected primary 2560x1440+0+1080 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 598mm x 336mm
   2560x1440     59.95*+  74.92
   2560x1080     60.00*+
```

It seems I may have the same hardware as OP, though maybe not the same motherboard, and almost certainly not the same BIOS, but it does work as expected. When the DVI cable is used instead of DisplayPort, it shows up as connected to HDMI-2. VGA when used shows up as DP-2.

Note the difference in CRTC names. This is a consequence of using the advanced technology upstream default DDX driver, modesetting, instead of the older technology Intel DDX driver. It could be that a switch to the modesetting DDX would solve this issue, done by simply removing the package providing the intel DDX driver, and restarting X.

I suspect the more likely root problem is a defective BIOS, but I'd try another (unrelated; live) distro or two first, and the modesetting DDX, before looking at the BIOS as cause.

Comment: This post sounds like advice on how to further investigate rather than a definitive answer to the OPs question. However, while it is true that the OP stated "I'm not sure what the next step for debugging this would be", troubleshooting hints are unlikely to be helpful anymore considering the age of the question. Perhaps you can reformulate your answer as a definitive solution, in particular if you intended it to be one.

Comment: @AdminBee As I read it, OP specifically asked for a next debugging step: "I'm not sure what the next step for debugging this would be."